# Determining values k for which F(x,y,z,w) = k is a smooth hypersurface

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Simple question from Sally's Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis.

Sally defines a smooth hypersurface as a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the equation $$F(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n) = k$$ with the property that $\nabla F\neq 0 $ at each point in this set.

In Excercise 5.6.7, he gives the function

$F(x,y,z,w) = x^2sin (y) + y^2sin(z) -zwe^{xy}
$

He asks 'For what values of $k$ does the equation $F(x,y,z,w) = k$ define a smooth hypersurface?' I'm tempted to say that $F(x,y,z,w) = k$ is a smooth hypersurface for $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but I'm not too sure. My thought process is as follows:

$F(x,y,z,w)$ is not a smooth hypersurface at points where  \begin{align} 
2xsin(y)-yzwe^{xy} &= 0 \\
x^2cos(y) + 2ysin(z) -xzwe^{xy} &=0 \\
y^2cos(z) - we^{xy} &= 0 \\
-ze^{xy} &= 0
\end{align}
By the final equation, we must have that $z=0$.  So the problem reduces to finding where the $G(x,y,w) = x^2sin(y) = k$ is a smooth hypersurface. If $x^2sin(y) = 0$, then it contains the point $(0,y,w)$, at which $\nabla G(x,y,w) = 0$. If $x^2sin(y)\neq 0$, then $2xsin(y)\neq 0$ so $G(x,y,w)$ is a smooth hypersurface for $k\neq 0$.

Is my thought process correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this seems correct.